# Get all the URLs of the pages that uses a specific shortcode

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode

For example my *example.com/sample-page/* is using `[my_shortcode param="1"]`.

How can I get all the URLs of the pages that uses `[my_shortcode]`?

Is there an approach to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think there is already an implementation for this. You'd probably need to get all posts and check if the shortcode exists in each individually

Comment: @kero I've shared my solution, **now I'm solving how to get the shortcode params.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that I've found:

```
  $pages = get_pages();
  $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();

  foreach($pages as $page) {
    if ( preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $page->post_content, $matches )
      && array_key_exists( 2, $matches )
      && in_array( 'my_shortcode', $matches[2] ) )
    {
      echo $page->post_title . <br />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: According [to the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_shortcode_regex/), you should be able to simply use `get_shortcode_regex(array('my_shortcode'))` and save yourself the trouble of comparing the `$matches`

Comment: @kero Thank you.. but I can get the used params on `$matches[3]` with that approach.

Comment: Yeah, but your regex is really expensive if you check for all shortcodes. `preg_match_all()` might take a long time to execute, so using a simpler regex will probably make it alot faster

Comment: WordPress has a function, `has_shortcode()` which can be used for checking if a shortcode exists.